# Ubuntu Server 16.04 - display hostname instead of IP in password prompt (SSHD)

Tags: server, ssh, password

Over the years I saw several different password prompts when SSHing to a server, some are just "Password:", then we have "username@server_ip password:" or "username@server_hostname password:".
In my case, when I just installed Ubuntu Server, I have the "username@server_ip" as the prompt, and of course, it displays different IP depending if I try to log in from local network or over internet. But what I'd preffer is if it shown the server's own hostname instead of IP address.

Let's say, I have a user named foo and the server's own hostname is bar, so I'd want it to display "foo@bar password:".

Anyone know how to change it? I tried googling up and found several things for different distributions (some mentioning sshd_config, others pam.d, some even locale files) but nothing seems to be accurate for Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried editing `/etc/pam.d/sshd.` as mentioned [here?](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/38184/)

Comment: @ElderGeek It's actually one of the pages that I found, but it only refers to making a fully custom prompt. So if I made it "authtok_prompt=foo@bar\ password:", then the user 'fab' were to connect, they'd be greeted with:
login as: fab
foo@bar password:

Comment: Have you considered using the environment variables $USER and $HOSTNAME in your custom prompt? Sorry I can't test this but it would seem logical to try. There appears to be a related discussion [here.](http://superuser.com/questions/221001/pushing-my-ps1-prompt-over-ssh)

Comment: @ElderGeek Well, I just tried it, and nothing seems to affect it whatsoever. Neither setting it to "$USER@$HOSTNAME", "$USER@my_hostname", or even just simply "password:". I guess authtok_prompt isn't implemented in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

That prompt is from your ssh client, not from the server; it is essentially parroting back to you whatever identifier you used in the ssh command line:

From [sshconnect2.c](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sshconnect2.c?rev=1.254&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup):`auth_passwd()`:

```
snprintf(prompt, sizeof(prompt), "%.30s@%.128s's password: ",
    authctxt->server_user, host);
```

If you have set a `HostKeyAlias` option, it will use that name rather than the IP address or hostname you used on the command line.  Add to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host some_alias
    Hostname 192.168.1.13
    HostKeyAlias something_else
```

Comment: Well, this is in case I was using SSH on linux to connect to a server, but I'm using Putty on Windows. But even then, that doesn't explain why for some servers I've been connecting to it was showing the machine's own hostname, instead of IP.